# Findall with array of string groovy

Tags: groovy, split, findall

I have a string `/sample/data`. When I split using `split` I get the following result,

`["","sample","data"]`

I want to ignore the empty string(s). So I tried the following code,

```
"/sample/data".split('/').findAll(it != "")
```

It gives me an error "`cannot call String[] findAll with argument bool`".

How can I split and get a List without empty string in it?

Comment: Use curly braces, not parens. The findAll method expects a closure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do as below:

```
println "/sample/data".split('/').findAll {it}
```

`findAll {it}` would fetch all the non empty values.

Answer (score 3):

**split** method returns array.
If you need List, use **tokenize**

```
"/sample/data".tokenize('/')
```

also you don't need to use findAll in this case.

Answer (score 1):

Parens would work (see comments on question).  So your solution is already close:

```
"/a/b".split("/").findAll()
```

Because most of the Groovy functions have a zero arity, which will call the function with an *identity* closure.  And since an empty string is considered falsey, this will filter them out.